# Error making/compiling objective C file

Tags: objective-c, makefile

Today I had my first lesson in Objective_C, it was about how to create "HELLO WORLD". After I downloaded the compiler and wrote the program I had to run it through the "shell" ,as stated in the tutorial, using the command "make" but i receive "No target specified and no makefile found. stop" error

To note, I program objectivec under windows OS

main.m Code:

```
//
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
NSLog(@"***Sweet tutos***\n");
NSLog(@"***Hello World!***\n");//This will output Hello World!

[pool release];
return 0;
```

}

GNU makfile:

```
 # This script was developed for SweetTutos Tutorials
 # www.sweettutos.wordpress.com
 #
 include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/common.make
 # make a simple program in Objective-C, call it SweetTutos
 TOOL_NAME = SweetTutos
 # The implementation Objective-C file which is going to be compiled
 SweetTutos_OBJC_FILES = main.m
 # Header files of your project
 #SweetTutos_HEADER_FILES = xxx.h //here goes all header files (.h). For the moment, 
 on n'en a pas.
 # Define compilation flags
 ADDITIONAL_CPPFLAGS = -Wall -Wno-import
 # Include rules for creating a command line tool for Objective-C
 include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/tool.make
```

Comment: What is the actual name of the makefile? Was "GNU makfile" a typo?

Answer (score 0):

"no makefile found" usually means you have no file [named literally `GNUmakefile`, `makefile` or `Makefile`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Makefile-Names) in the current directory (or the directory pointed at if you use `-C`).

In the `Makefile` you need to [specify at least one rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Rule-Example) so that `make` can do something. The first rule in the file (sequentially, not chronologically) becomes the [default rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#How-Make-Works), so you *don't* actually have to specify a target like the error message indicates.

Comment: what is -C?? in the tutorial, it instructs to use keyword "make" to execute the program which is called "main.m" without succeeding the keyword "make" with file name, is this right?

Comment: `man make` explains it well: "-C dir: Change  to  directory  dir  before reading the makefiles or doing anything else."